# How to set position of a div over another div with same position in all screen widths

Tags: html, css

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/w7r3gveg/]1
```

I have 4 facebook logos and wants to be center bottom of my background image.

Div bg is background 
div facebook is facebook logo.

I can set facebook logo center of bg div, but It's not responsive.

I want to lock facebook logo over bg div, so If a user changed screen width or have a different screen width facebook logo should be locked in the same position as other widths based bg div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

### JsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/46psK/2983/

### HTML

```
<div class="responsive-container">
    <div class="dummy"></div>

    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="http://s2.uploads.im/t/8LauQ.png" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

### css

```
.responsive-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.dummy {
    padding-top: 100%; /* forces 1:1 aspect ratio */
}

.img-container {
    background-image: url("http://s2.uploads.im/t/VtT8j.png");
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
         background-position: center; 
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    text-align:center; /* Align center inline elements */
    font: 0/0 a;
}

.img-container:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}

.img-container img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: seems like working, just an issue: when I change screen to very small about 320 width then facebook logo will be big. cause I wants to use 4 social network side to side. Is there any way to stay same size as img-contaner size in all widths ?

Comment: Now Inner image also responsive,hope this suit. check here. https://jsfiddle.net/a8h4v9y8/

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a few changes in your code. In **HTML** remove `col-xs-1` class in `.facebook` elements, like:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="facebook"></div>
    <div class="facebook"></div>
    <div class="facebook"></div>
    <div class="facebook"></div>
</div>
```

In **CSS** just add:

```
.bg .col-xs-6{
    text-align: center;
}

.facebook{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/w7r3gveg/1/)

Comment: @Imgonzalves it seems no responsive , when i shrink the window its not responsive.

Comment: Take a look at [this new demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/w7r3gveg/2/). Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: It's not responsive. change window width you will see facebook logo position will be changed.